# employer ignoring my request of contract paper copy

Tags: contracts, employer-relations

I signed a contract of 1.5 years i.e. 18 months of the bond period with my employer in Dec 2016. The contract says that I'll have to serve 3 months notice period after I put my papers. Now I am requesting a copy of my contract for personal reference and the HR is just ignoring my messages. What should I do?

Comment: "What should I do?" questions are hard to answer within the context of Stack Exchange, and your problem seems to deal with company-specific issues. If you can frame up a specific goal or outcome and/or ask a question that isn't so open-ended you'll likely get better help.

Comment: Why didn't you get a copy when you signed the contract?

Comment: Gather together what documentation you have of your asking for a copy of your contract and go speak with a lawyer.  Depending on your location, I wouldn't think it's legal to deny you a copy, and you should've got one when you first started.

Comment: @Roland why does it matter now?

Comment: @dwizum I read the implicit question as "How can I get a copy of the contract?"

Answer (score 2):

Are you worried about 3 month notice period?

IMO, it is depending on your location and how chummy you want to be with your employer.

If you are in US and DON`T plan to remain with this employer, you can speak to labor lawyer and ask him to draw a official request letter. That can get their attention.

In case of personal inquiry, registered letter directed to head of HR department will get you started. Given he would have to sign for it, there will be implied clock on the request.

And, if you need it for your own records and not planning on doing anything with it, courteous personal visit to the HR could help. Donuts always a winner ;)